# Drools - Running a rule with an empty object

Tags: eclipse, object, if-statement, conditional-statements, drools

I'm trying to write a rule to calculate prices for an insurance product based on conditions. In the 'when' I'm using an object called AdditionalDriver, which contains the details for drivers other than the policy holder. From this, different prices can be calculated based on whether the additional driver is a parent, friend, spouse etc. See below:

```
when
    AdditionalDriver($relToProp : relationToProposer)
then
    String relToProp = $relToProp;

    if(!relToProp.equals("P"))
    {
        //prices
    }
end
```

"P" = parent.

This rule works when an additional driver has been added. However, if there is no additional driver, then the object is empty, and so the rule does not run. What do I need to do to get this rule to run, even when the object is empty?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is an "empty object"? An object exists, with the fields as defined by its class code, constructor and initialisation, or it does nor exist.

Comment: Thanks for your question laune. I guess what I mean is that it doesn't exist. Some policies will have an additional driver and some won't, and it's the latter where the problems occur, as the rule does not fire.

Answer (score 0):

You should write one rule for each of the relative or acquaintance classes:

```
when
    PolicyHolder( $phid: id )
    AdditionalDriver( relationToProposer == "P", belongsTo == $phid )
then 
    //prices
end
```

For no additional driver being requested, write a rule

```
when
    PolicyHolder( $phid: id )
    not AdditionalDriver( belongsTo == $phid )
then 
    // cheaper prices
end
```

Don't use conditional statement in your consequences to further distinguish facts. This is a code smell.